# React native map doesn't show up

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to use airbnb's react-native-maps for my react native app but the map is not showing up on the device. The instructions which are mentioned in the documentation ([here](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md)) are followed when installing the module. Also the permissions are added to the app in AndroidManifest file.

The build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
  }
}
```

dependency is added by following version to the bilde.gradle file inside the source folder

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
}
```

App.js file

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import {AppRegistry, Text, View} from 'react-native';
 import Component6 from './app/components/Component6/Component6'
 import UsersMap from './app/components/Component6/UsersMap'

 export default class App extends Component {

 getLocationHandler = () => { 
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    console.log(position);
    }, err =>  console.log(err));
 }

 render() {
    return (
       <View>
         <Component6 onGetLocation={this.getLocationHandler} />
          <UsersMap />
       </View>
     );
   } 
 }


 AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

Component6.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-native';

const fetchLocation = props => {
    return(
        <Button title="Get Location" onPress = {props.onGetLocation} 
          />
        );
    };
  export default fetchLocation;
```

UsersMap.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const usersMap = props => {
     return(
          <View styles={styles.mapContainer}>
                <MapView styles={styles.map}/>
          </View>
      );
  };

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   mapContainer : {
      width : '100%',
      height : 200
    },
   map : {
      width : '100%',
      height : '100%'
    }
  });
export default usersMap;
```

The `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` returns the current location to the console but the map is not showing up on the device. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps#my-map-is-blank it looks like you're not applying the right styles to the map. Another common cause is that the API key isn't correctly configured, see this issue: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/354

Comment: I followed your first point but it remains the same. and regarding the second point, there is no error mentioning about the API key.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the package doesn't throw an error if your api key is wrong or null, but if you put it correctly it should work.